# Sending HTTPOnly cookie in response using Rails API application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api, httponly, cookie-httponly

Correct me if I'm wrong but cookies are just special `Set-Cookie:` headers, right? Maybe I'm missing something but that always seemed like the case to me. If I set up a Rails API application and want to support sending HTTPOnly cookies (e.g. headers also assume I've got CORS and everything on the client setup etc) I should be able to do this correct?

Basically, my questions are these:

1. Does bringing back `ActionDispatch::Cookies` into my middleware and adding `include ::ActionController::Cookies` in my application controller totally defeat the purpose of an API application?
2. If it does, can I just send an HTTPOnly cookie through the headers manually?
3. And if that is so, is it a much bigger hassle to manage cookie headers manually? Is what I'm gaining from leaving the cookie middleware out out weigh handling them manually, if all I really need to do is send one HTTPOnly refresh token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I don't need to add back any middleware or include any classes for cookies. I can use `reponse.set_header` to send a cookie. However, this only lets you send one `Set-Cookie` header because it will overwrite the last header you set with `Set-Cookie` as the key. Instead you have access to `response.set_cookie` which will let you set multiple cookies with each `set_cookie` call. It also comes with some options that you can set that you would have to add to the value of the header you were sending manually with `set_header`.

Here's an example I used that allowed me to send a cookie:

```rb
response.set_cookie(
  :jwt,
  {
    value: 'this could be a token or whatever cookie value you wanted.',
    expires: 7.days.from_now,
    path: '/api/v1/auth',
    httponly: true
  }
)
```

Check the documentation for this method for other options because there are others.

**EDIT:** I was having an issue where the cookie was getting sent in the response but not saved (still). It wasn't showing up in the cookie storage so I changed the path of the cookie getting sent to `/` and then it showed up. I deleted it and then changed the cookie's path to `/my/real/path` and it worked and was stored in cookie storage. Go figure.

Comment: what if you need to add an encrypted cookie?

Comment: @AliGhanavatian good question. Use this documentation to determine how to do that. `secure` I think is what you want: https://apidock.com/rails/Rack/Response/set_cookie . If not, you can set key/value pairs (I'm assuming secure is what you want though) in the cookie.